# imagemagic: Convert -gravity center not working

Tags: imagemagick

I have a bunch of images and trying to convert them to pdf using the below command:

```
$ convert *.jpg -resize 1240x1753 \ 
                      -extent 1240x1753 -gravity center -background white \
                      -units PixelsPerInch -density 150x150 multipage.pdf
```

It makes a pdf of A4 size. But the images are not centered. They are movied to NorthWest side. How to ensure the images are centered (both side ways and up and down)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Put `-gravity center` before the `-extend` option:

```
convert *.jpg -resize 1240x1753 -background white \
    -gravity center -extent 1240x1753 \
    -units PixelsPerInch -density 150x150 multipage.pdf
```

Comment: Any explanation of why the order of the options would be helpful & appreciated.

Comment: You need to center the image before you set the its size with [-extend](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#extent) 
or it won't have an effect.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  Perhaps I am having the same problem.  I invite you to review: https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/634115/182280