# ImageMagick -gravity: portrait-photo frame-of-reference rotated +90

Tags: imagemagick, image-manipulation

## Context

[iPhone photos](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1obRBGwb-gA6Ij8emITjul6TzFOD_0_ug/view?usp=sharing) of both: portrait & landscape to be time-stamped with EXIF data, via ImageMagick 7.0.10-62 Q16 x86_64 2021-02-07  + Catalina MacOs.  ImageMagick installed via:`brew install ImageMagick`

## LANDSCAPE images follow gravity map:

The `-gravity` option specifies a frame of reference for annotating images.  Annotated **Landscape**-Orientation photos follow the convention.

[image]  [image]

## Issue: PORTRAIT Image Annotations are rotated

Annotated **Portrait**-orientation photos result in a rotated frame of reference:

[image]           [image]

Relevant code:

```
rm time*.jpeg
tic=$(date)
for img in IMG*jpeg; do convert "$img" -gravity Center -resize 35% -pointsize 65 \
   -fill red  -annotate +30+30  %[exif:DateTimeOriginal] "time_""$img";
   echo "watermarked $img successfully" 
done
toc=$(date)
echo $tic 
echo $toc
```

## Questions

Although an algorithm could be applied to rotate the text if a portrait image is detected, I would think that there is a simpler method or that the above code is somehow incorrect resulting in the +90 rotated frame of reference.  Landscape photos do not suffer this issue.

1. Why is the gravity frame of reference rotated 90 degrees for portrait-orientation images and not landscape images? (feature or flaw?)
2. How does one employ a consistent / singular `gravity` frame of reference?

   - preferably the non-rotated frame of reference

Comment: This is difficult to reproduce without the originals. 
Please add two source images, portrait and landscape including Exif data to the question. Also add the results and the expected results (6 images in total).

Comment: @Freddy   Thanks for engaging.  Photos uploaded to Google Drive https://drive.google.com/file/d/1obRBGwb-gA6Ij8emITjul6TzFOD_0_ug/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The portrait image is rotated via the Exif `Orientation` tag. So the added timestamp is correct if we rotate the image.

portait image (rotated via Exif):

```
$ identify -verbose IMG_6361.jpeg | grep Orientation
  Orientation: RightTop
    exif:Orientation: 6
$ exiftool IMG_6361.jpeg | grep 'Orient\|Width\|Height'
Orientation                     : Rotate 90 CW
Exif Image Width                : 4032
Exif Image Height               : 3024
Image Width                     : 4032
Image Height                    : 3024
```

landscape image (not rotated):

```
$ identify -verbose IMG_1690.jpeg | grep Orientation
  Orientation: TopLeft
    exif:Orientation: 1
$ exiftool IMG_1690.jpeg | grep 'Orient\|Width\|Height'
Orientation                     : Horizontal (normal)
Exif Image Width                : 4032
Exif Image Height               : 3024
Image Width                     : 4032
Image Height                    : 3024
```

To change the orientation to "top-left", you can use ImageMagick's [-auto-orient](https://imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#auto-orient) option, e.g.

```
$ convert -auto-orient IMG_6361.jpeg IMG_6361_auto_orient.jpeg
$ exiftool IMG_6361_auto_orient.jpeg | grep 'Orient\|Width\|Height'
Orientation                     : Horizontal (normal)
Exif Image Width                : 4032
Exif Image Height               : 3024
Image Width                     : 3024
Image Height                    : 4032
```

Include `-auto-orient` in your command to:

```
for img in IMG*jpeg; do convert "$img" -auto-orient -gravity Center -resize 35% -pointsize 65 \
   -fill red  -annotate +30+30  %[exif:DateTimeOriginal] "time_""$img";
   echo "watermarked $img successfully" 
done
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation: it is an excellent example of how to explain an abstract problem and its solution.